# Dynamically adding columns to DataGridView as it gets expanded

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, ms-office

I'm working on a MS Office add-in that has a DataGridView with 5 columns. Is it possible to only  have as many columns shown as can fit into the sidebar, but then as the user re-sizes the add-in sidebar add more or take away columns as there becomes room for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use the Resize Event of the Datagridview and Add and Remove (or set visibilty) of all rows that are unwanted.

I guess your columns have a given size and are not sized automatically.

In that case u can:

```
int columnsToShow = (int)(dataGridView.Size.Width / columnWidth);
```

now add enough rows to match the wanted number / remove all rows that are too much
or set visibility

Comment: I think that what should be used is dataGridView.Size.ActualWidth

Comment: There is no attribute called ActualWidth under Size